# Apache Nifi for MS SQL CDC using dynamic SQL query

Tags: sql-server, apache-nifi, apache-phoenix, hortonworks-dataflow

In our legacy architecture, we have a MS SQL server database, this database stores all the sensor information in near real time basis, on average per second it receives 100 records.In order to get complete information about the sensor events, we need to join 2 to 3 tables in the database.

```
Sample Query:

SELECT SOMETHING
FROM TABLE1 AS tab1 
INNER JOIN TABLE2 AS tab2 ON tab1.UpdateID=tab2.ID 
INNER JOIN TABLE3 as tab3 ON tab1.TagID=tab3.ID 
WHERE tab2.UpdateTime > ${lastExtractUnixTime}
```

Our requirement is to get the capture data change of above query every 1 minute and post records to Kafka.

Temporarily I am doing CDC using Spark Core JDBC, processing records, sending to Kafka and maintaining CDC information along with `${lastExtractUnixTime}` into HBase as Phoenix table. Job is scheduled for every 1 minute batch interval.

As a long term solution, we are planning to use Apache Nifi for doing the CDC thing and post information to Kafka, Spark streaming will read messages from Kafka, will apply some business logic on it and will send the enriched data to the other Kafka topic; I don't find suitable processor, which will help me to dynamically pass the `${lastExtractUnixTime}` in SQL and get the delta records every 1 or 2 minutes.

Please suggest how this can be accomplished using Apache Nifi.

Comment: Instead of CDC use [Change tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server). It's a lot faster and lighter than CDC and definitely faster than Apache Nifi. It doesn't *copy* data, it keeps track of changed (ie inserted, deleted, updated) records in internal tables. You can specify that only the keys will be stored or all columns. You can use it to get only the records that changed since the last check. You can join the changed keys with the actual tables to retrieve more data and send it to Kafka

Comment: Change tracking is available in *all* editions of SQL Server, from LocalDB upwards. CDC is only available in Enterprise editions

Comment: If you only track keys, you could write `SELECT .. FROM Table1 .. INNER JOIN CHANGETABLE(CHANGES TABLE2, @last_synchronization_version) CT on CT.ID=Table2.ID` to get only the records that changed since the last sync. `SYS_CHANGE_OPERATION` will show the type of change and SYS_CHANGE_VERSION  each record's change version.

Comment: @nilesh1212 which solution did you end up with? is the solution stable?

Comment: @j9dy  We are not using Nifi for this use case, using traditional CDC solutions